# How to use two for-loops to make a grid of numbers?

Tags: python, for-loop

I define the function of `draw_grid`:

```
def draw_grid(num):
    grid = ''
    for i in range(1, num + 1):     #  + 1 because if  you don't then you will get the output of your integer - 1
        new_grid =(str(i)+ ' ' + str(grid))
        print(new_grid, end='')

draw_grid(4)
```

This outputs  `1 2 3 4`,  but I need to use another for loop to basically repeat this so it will look like a grid with those numbers repeated 4 more times.

Question: How do I use another for loop to make a grid of numbers?

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Firstly, get rid of some cruft: `grid` does literally nothing and `new_grid` is pointless when you could just do `print(i, end=' ')`. Now onto the question, what's your expected output? What have you already tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your sample expected output to the question summary.

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution if it helps, not sure if the loop method is a requirement or just the way you decided to go about it without knowing all the possibilities:

```
import numpy as np
num = 4
grid = np.tile(np.array([range(num)])+1,(num,1))

print(grid)

[[1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like:

```
def draw_grid(num):
    # Two loops for xy indices
    grid = ""
    for j in range(num):
        for i in range(num):
            grid += (str(i+1) + " ")
        grid += "\n"

    print(grid)
    return grid

draw_grid(4)
```

Then the output is:

```
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop over `range(num)` (which I assume is where the number 4 comes from in your example). I've made some other improvements to the code as well:

```
def draw_grid(num):
    r = range(1, num+1)
    for i in r:  # Since "i" isn't used, we can use "r" instead of "range(num)"
        print(*r)  # The star expands "r" into its items

draw_grid(4)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using Python 3 `f-strings`:

```
def draw_grid(x):
    for _ in range(x):
        print(''.join(f'{_+1} ' for _ in range(x)))
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 12 2019, 14:45:07) 
[GCC 9.1.1 20190605 (Red Hat 9.1.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def draw_grid(x):
...     for _ in range(x):
...         print(''.join(f'{_+1} ' for _ in range(x)))
... 
>>> draw_grid(5)
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
>>> draw_grid(10)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
>>>
```

And finally, here is a one-liner version:

```
def draw_grid(x):
    print(*[''.join([f'{_+1} ' for _ in range(x)]) for _ in range(x)], sep='\n')
```